# compare two dates in Postgressql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two table

job1

```
id(c-v) | joiningDate(character-varying)
--+--
1 | 2020-10-05
2 | 2023-10-05
3 | 2021-01-01
```

job2

```
id(c-v) | joiningDate(character-varying)
--+--
1 | 2020-10-05
2 | 2023-10-05
```

Here is sql query

```
SELECT max(j1."joiningDate")
    FROM public.job1 j1 left join public.job2 j2 ON j1.id=j2.id and 
    j1."joiningDate"  <= TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

I'm trying to fetch the maximum date which is less than current date.. for the I'm getting the empty data..
what would be the issue?

Comment: What is the expected output and why?

Comment: **Never**, ever store `date` or `integer` values in `varchar` columns.

Comment: There is no problem with your comparing dates. Please explain the relation of job1 and job2 and how you want to calculate max(joiningdate)

Comment: Please provide what you expected to receive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I view the purpose of the join as being a filter on only jobs which match in both tables.  If so, then what you really want here is an *inner* join, and the check on the date being the current date or earlier should be moved to the where clause.  Putting this together, perhaps this is what you need here:

```sql
SELECT MAX(j1.joiningDate)
FROM public.job1 j1
INNER JOIN public.job2 j2
    ON j1.id = j2.id
WHERE
    j1.joiningDate::date <= CURRENT_DATE;
```

Note: Consider making the `joiningDate` column an actual date column in both tables.

Comment: I don't see the benefit of `LIMIT` over a mere `MAX`. The query's main difference is that you moved the date condition to `WHERE` which should lead to a result of 2023-10-05 instead of 2021-01-01. You don't explain why the original query doesn't return a value. The other difference in your query is that you don't convert `CURRENT_DATE` to a string, but `joiningdate` to a date. This is a good idea. Invalid data in that column would thus lead to an exception and may even explain why the original query doesn't seem to get a result. It may be because of control chars in the result. +1 for this.

Answer (score 1):

The query you are showing should not result  in NULL, but in 2023-10-05 (the maximum date in the table). This is what you have:

```
SELECT max(j1.joiningDate)
FROM public.job1 j1
LEFT OUTER JOIN public.job2 j2 ON <conditions>
```

You see that the table job2 has no impact on the result (and nothing to do with the task at hand as far as I can see).

You want a `WHERE` clause to restrict the rows to dates before today:

```
WHERE j1.joiningDate <= TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

The whole query:

```
SELECT max(j1.joiningDate)
FROM public.job1 j1
WHERE j1.joiningDate <= TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

If you are really getting null (or no result) with your original query, then this is not a problem with the query. You should get a result as mentioned (albeit not the desired result at that). It must be your tool or app. Or you are not showing the complete query. Or there is no data in table job1.